# If-Else Condition inside cursor not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am having a procedure where i need to check the status in the table which is present in other server and need to update it.

Here is my stored procedure ..please check

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testproceudre]    
AS       
DECLARE @Status INT     
DECLARE @UpdatedDateTime DATETIME    
DECLARE @STSFLG INT    
--dynamic query variables       

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(4000)     
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(4000)     
DECLARE @DBSTRING VARCHAR(1000)     
DECLARE @TABLESTR VARCHAR(200)       
BEGIN     

 SET @DBSTRING = '[server name].[db name]'        
 SET @TABLESTR = ''     

 DECLARE @SYSproUploadflag INT    
 DECLARE @DpCodeExist INT    

 SET @SYSproUploadflag = 0     
 SET @DpCodeExist = 0     
 SET @TABLESTR = @DBSTRING+'.[dbo].[otherservertablename]'     
 SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Status INT,@UpdatedDateTime DATETIME'    
 SET @SQLString ='SELECT StatusFlg,ConfirmedDate FROM localtablename
 JOIN '+ @TABLESTR +' ON     
 IssuesId=SFAIssueId WHERE Statusflg=4'     

 EXECUTE sp_executesql     
 @SQLString,     
 @ParmDefinition,     
 @Status = @Status,     
 @UpdatedDateTime = @UpdatedDateTime     
 BEGIN     
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  IF @SYSproUploadflag = 0     
  BEGIN  
   DECLARE PARKCURSOR CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT STATUS FROM [server name].[db name].[dbo].[otherservertablename]
   JOIN localtablename ON SFAISSUEID = ISSUESID
   OPEN  PARKCURSOR
   FETCH NEXT FROM PARKCURSOR 
   INTO @STSFLG
   WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
   BEGIN
        IF(@STSFLG = 3)
        BEGIN
           UPDATE issue2 SET status = 4,UpdatedDateTime=ConfirmedDate,
           SOURCEOFUPDATION = 'SFA'     
           FROM [server name].[db name].[dbo].[otherservertablename] issue2  JOIN     
           tblAHCIssues issue1    
           ON issue2.sfaissueid=issue1.issuesid 
        END
        IF(@STSFLG = 2)
        BEGIN
           UPDATE issue2 SET status = 7,UpdatedDateTime=ConfirmedDate,
           SOURCEOFUPDATION = 'SFA'     
           FROM [server name].[db name].[dbo].[otherservertablename] issue2  JOIN     
           localtablename issue1    
           ON issue2.sfaissueid=issue1.issuesid  
        END  
        FETCH NEXT FROM PARKCURSOR INTO  @STSFLG 
   END
    CLOSE PARKCURSOR 
    DEALLOCATE PARKCURSOR 
  END     
 END        
END
```

My Prob is if the status is 2 in all rows it is updating as 7
if 3 in all rows it is updating as 4
but if some are 3 and some are 2, then the first row what is there , with respect to that only it is updating all the values.that means if 1st row is having status as 3 and second row as 2 it is updating both as 4.but it should update first as 4 and second as  7.can any one help me what mistake i am doing???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no where clause in your update - each of those updates will update exactly the same set of rows (i.e. all those rows in issue2 where there is a matching issue in localtablename).

This means that the end result will depend on what the last status ID was in your cursor.